# Is there some way to handle the FlyoutBase.ContextFlyout menu open event in MAUI?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have a context menu for each item in the CollectionView.
Depending on the context, it is necessary to add/remove some menu items. There is no isVisible property on MenuItem, so I want to control the items manually.
Maybe there is an event of pressing the right mouse button and a method of manually opening the context menu?

upd:
So far, I see only this way of solving the problem:
Create a single context menu in the ViewModel, bind it to the CollectionView and change the items in the SelectionChanged event.
This solution has a few issues, like right-clicking on an object that is not selected, so I'm looking for a better option.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Attached Property that you can use to do this as far as I know:

```
 <MenuItem Text="Help"
          IconImageSource="help.png"
          Shell.FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"
          Command="{Binding HelpCommand}"
          CommandParameter="https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell" />
```

More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout#flyoutitem-visibility)

Hope this helps!

Comment: We are talking about <FlyoutBase.ContextFlyout> <MenuFlyout> <MenuFlyoutItem> in .Net 7

Unfortunately, it won't work there

Comment: Well, you did not mention that in your question was I supposed to guess that? All ur question says is menu items, so I guessed it was the regular ones... Please add ur code

Comment: I indicated in the header that it was about FlyoutBase.ContextFlyout

Comment: Can you please show us your current code in that case

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/7.0/Fundamentals/ContextMenu/ContextMenuSample) example

Comment: Why are you not adding this through c# code instead so you can perform conditional compilation?